# Why does declare -F give the wrong file

Tags: bash, bash-functions

I have 2 small functions to abbreviate `set -x` / `set +x`, namely:

```
sx () {
    export PS4='+ [${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:${LINENO}]'
    set -x
}
```

and

```
sz () {
    set +x
    export PS4=
}
```

These 2 functions are in a file `functons.sh` which is [source](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html)d from `~/.bashrc`, and visible online [here](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/eec3fef3a8f9471f594b4c452cc80cd0a6676e55/src/bash/functons.sh#L428).

Immediately after logging in to a new bash session, I try to find out where the `sz()` function is like this:

```
$ shopt -s extdebug; declare -F sz; shopt -u extdebug
sz 25 /Users/jab/src/git/hub/jab/src/bash/keyboard/z.sh
```

This shows that `bash` thinks the `sz()` function is declared in `z.sh`, but at that line there is a different function, `zzz()`, online [here](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/eec3fef3a8f9471f594b4c452cc80cd0a6676e55/src/bash/keyboard/z.sh#L25).

The result for the `sx()` function (and all my myriad other functions) is correct

```
$ shopt -s extdebug; declare -F sx; shopt -u extdebug
sx 428 /Users/jab/src/git/hub/jab3/src/bash/functons.sh
```

Why does the `declare -F` command get the wrong result for the `sz` function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You also have an alias in `functons.sh`with the same name as a function in your other file.

In `functons.sh`:

```
alias zzz=sz
```

In `z.sh`:

```
zzz () {
    df -h
}
```

This confuses `bash`.

Example:

```
$ cat f1
foo () { echo hello; }
alias xfoo=foo

$ cat f2
xfoo () { echo beep; }

$ source f1
$ source f2
$ shopt -s extdebug
$ declare -F foo
foo 1 f2
```

Without the `xfoo` alias in `f1`:

```
$ source f1
$ source f2
$ shopt -s extdebug
$ declare -F foo
foo 1 f1
```

---

The `bash` manual also includes the text

> Aliases are confusing in some uses.

under the "BUGS" heading.

Comment: That's [the fix](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/commit/c4fc8a45f3f192bcc9dd4949cb207fc3823ae4b8)! Thanks for helping me see what was staring me in the face :-)